An instance of a class that is initialized with data from a file in Dart
i am new to dart I would like to find out how to write a code in dart for An instance of a class that is initialized with data from a file
void main() async {
  final file = File('OOP\movie_metadata.csv');
  Stream<String> lines =
      file.openRead().transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter());

  try {
    await for (var line in lines) {
      print('$line : ${line.length} characters');
    }
    print('file is closed');
  } catch (e) {
    print('error : $e');
  }
}


this what i  tried and i keep getting this error : PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'OOPmovie_metadata.csv' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
, errno = 2)``

As the error message says, the file wasn't found at that path.  Since you specified a relative path, that file needs to exist in the current working directory for your process.  Ensure that Directory.current is set to the directory where your file is located or use an absolute path instead.

Your string literal contains a \m escape. Either change \​ to \\​ or (better) make the string raw: File(r'OOP\movie_metadata.csv').
